# Spock does not execute when clause

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

One of my spock tests is skipping the `when` clause and moving right to the `then` clause.

```
@Unroll
void "test refresh metadata with #consumerNames"() {
    setup:
    consumerNames.each {
        new CredentialConsumer(name: it).save(validate: false)
    }

    when:
    service.refreshMetadata()

    then:
    consumerNames.each { consumerName ->
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata(content: "Metadata for $consumerName")
        ConsumerDefinition consumerDefinition = new ConsumerDefinition(name: consumerName, metadata: metadata)
        1 * mockApplicationLibraryService.fetchConsumerDefinition(consumerName) >> consumerDefinition
        assert CredentialConsumer.findByName(consumerName)?.metadata?.content == metadata.content
    }

    where:
    consumerNames     | _
    ["bacon"]         | _
    ["bacon", "eggs"] | _

}
```

I get the following results...

```
Condition not satisfied:

CredentialConsumer.findByName(consumerName)?.metadata?.content == metadata.content
                   |          |              |         |       |  |        |
                   |          bacon          null      null    |  |        Metadata for bacon
                   |                                           |  com.datapriviasoftware.completesso.configuration.Metadata@487cd177
                   |                                           false
                   com.datapriviasoftware.completesso.CredentialConsumer : 1

Expected :Metadata for bacon

Actual   :null
```

When I step through it with the debugger, it executes the `setup` clause, skips the `when` clause, and immediately executes the `then` clause.

Answer (score 0):

So, I knew that Spock uses AST transformations to process mocks in the `then` clause before it executes the `when` clause.  When I thought through it, I realized that processing the mocks in the `then` clause required the entire `each` loop to execute, so I needed to separate the explicit assertion from the mock definition.

**This works...**

```
@Unroll
void "test refresh metadata with #consumerNames"() {
    setup:
    consumerNames.each {
        new CredentialConsumer(name: it).save(validate: false)
    }

    when:
    service.refreshMetadata()

    then:
    consumerNames.each { consumerName ->
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata(content: "Metadata for $consumerName")
        ConsumerDefinition consumerDefinition = new ConsumerDefinition(name: consumerName, metadata: metadata)
        1 * mockApplicationLibraryService.fetchConsumerDefinition(consumerName) >> consumerDefinition
    }

    and:
    consumerNames.each { consumerName ->
        assert CredentialConsumer.findByName(consumerName)?.metadata?.content == "Metadata for $consumerName"
    }

    where:
    consumerNames     | _
    ["bacon"]         | _
    ["bacon", "eggs"] | _

}
```